# How to insert my own numbers into division query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that works well.  Only problem is it is dividing by a number of rows pulled from my database from the select statement.  How do I change

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saved_players))
```

to lets say 1000?  1000 being the total number of members.

```
$query= "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Total , (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saved_players)) * 100 AS totalnumber
FROM saved_players
GROUP BY fname";
```

So I am looking for something like below but it doesn't work.

```
$query= "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Total , (COUNT(*) / 1000 * 100 AS totalnumber
FROM saved_players
GROUP BY fname";
```

Comment: yes, it won't work, because you're missing a `)`... you've got 3 `(`, and only 2 `)`.

Comment: wow lol I just realized that.  Thanks for help @MarcB

Comment: never assume a query will succeed. always check for failure on your query calls. e.g. `$result = mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error(...));`. if you had even this sort of minimal error handling, you'd have been told about the syntax error.

Comment: I see what you mean I will for sure do that in the future.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query= "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Total , (COUNT(*) / 1000 * 100) AS totalnumber
FROM saved_players
GROUP BY fname";
```

Looks like missing bracket`)`.

Hope this helps